# how to apply css in container

Tags: html, css

[i haveproblem in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpZk6.png) i have used one container in that i have apply slick slider which value is dynamic.now but i want to add review to this particular block. but that word is going down from container 
  ***** Review  *
i have apply this code but still review is not coming exact below the image of slick slider..which css i should apply for it.i tried to apply margin,margin-top,padding,padding-top and so on.I am getting problem in apply css for that "review" which css should i apply so that the review comes exact below the image of slider.

Comment: Can you please add your code here.

Comment: also, try giving container position:absolute and to Review position:relative
bt post your code or link so that we can understand you better.

Comment: <span style='color:black;padding-top:10px;'><a href='Mail.aspx' > Review </a> </span>

Comment: oh andy. remove that span and put a <div> tag instead of it.

Comment: mam still not working i have apply div tag

Comment: can u plz tell me how to add imageherei am new to this..i will send u my pic

Comment: do u mean how to add image in slider? r u looking for slider code?

Comment: no i stackoverflow so that i can send u my screenshot..of what problem i am getting

Comment: edit your question again, there you will see option to upload an image.

Comment: hello i have added my image plz check it

Comment: okay. it is coming properly.. just repeating word "Review" right?
Try giving "review"s div width:100% in style

Comment: no i want that word review exact below the price

Comment: for that u need to post ur code here.. m unable to inspect it. post all your code. can u please? Its so easy just put your code in question.

Comment: which code .cs or aspx?

Comment: send complete code.. css and aspx both

Comment: sorry Mr. @Maharshi

Comment: haha.. i wont mind.. Mr. Maharshi @Maharshi

Answer (score 1):

See like this

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color:blue;">
  SLIDER IMAGEs
</div>
<div style='color:black; padding-top:10px;'>
  <a href='Mail.aspx'> Review </a> 
</div>
```